# Tensile Strength of Shear Strength for a fully supported member

Tags: structural-analysis, shear, tension

I have an extrusion that is fully supported and will bear a wheel load. Considering its fully supported, should I utilize the shear flow equation to assess it against factors such as tensile strength or shear strength? My inclination is towards shear strength. Would that be appropriate?

Comment: You should assess it for all that may cause a failure.  You have not given enough info regarding how the wheel loads the beam (directions matter).  What happens locally at the point of wheel/beam contact when the wheel is very small and very hard?